Why doesn't enqueueing messages in Erlang require a lock?
The Erlang runtime does attempt to take the lock of another running process if it is available, but it seems perfectly able to manipulate parts of the recieving process without taking the process's locks:
https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/erts/emulator/beam/erl_proc_sig_queue.c#L773
/* the message buffer is stored as a 
   pointer to the first message, and a pointer 
   to the address of the last message */

*this = first; /* `this` is the `last` of the destination queue */
dest_queue->last = last;

(comments mine)
The data being manipulated is not access-controlled by locks of any kind (at this point) (as far as I can tell), and yet it is safe in a parallel environment. I cannot determine why this is safe - surely two processes could attempt to modify these pointers at the same time, leading to a race? Or is it instead a precondition on these functions that locks must be taked?

Probably because of Erlang memory management where everything is basically a const. Erlang does not allow you to overwrite a variable, meaning it is safe to share a pointer/reference to a variable between threads (or really Erlang processes) without having to deal with that data is suddenly gone or changed.
This is why you often see Erlang code like this:
MyNumber = 3
UpdatedNumber = MyNumber + 1

Since MyNumber is always 3, it can safely be shared. Trying to overwrite MyNumber with a new integer is not allowed and if tried will result in a crash.

Apologies, but I'm referring to the internals of the Erlang runtime; not user code.

Aha, not that I am expert in C or Erlang internals, but the documentation hints that it should be locked, but the locking should be handled by the caller:
https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/64fcd877c7645cea51e0b532255cc602f6e9aad5/erts/emulator/beam/erl_proc_sig_queue.c#L764C1-L768C62
